# Who owns the rights of my bike ride track in an official race?

Tags: intellectual-property, data-ownership

Say I participate in an organized cycling (or running) event and say the event organizer has not published the track anywhere online and say the event organizer does not want the track to be publicly accessible.

Then, can the event organizer prohibit me from publishing my ride publicly on [Strava](http://strava.com) (Strava is a platform for uploading, sharing and investigating of sports activities such as cycling, running etc).

If I upload a GPX track to Strava, I accept the following conditions:

> “You grant us a non-exclusive, transferable, sub-licensable, royalty-free, worldwide license to use any Content that you post on or in connection with the Services.”

Since the rights asserted by Strava are quite extensive, I wonder whether the organizer can interdict my upload to keep the precise routing under lock and key.  On the flipside, I feel this would strongly restrict my liberty rights.

If this is not the right place to ask, please point me to a better forum.

Comment: If you don't like a restriction on your rights, don't agree to the restrictions. You may not like the consequence of the choice but the choice remains.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It depends on how you got the right to participate in the event. Let us assume that you "sign up" for the event, and agree to certain conditions in exchange for being allowed to participate. In that case, there could be a condition prohibiting you from tracking the route, or publicizing the track: you have to read what the agreement says. Agreement might be necessary if the track is on private property (you need permission, otherwise you're trespassing).

If this is a run on city streets, you can (possibly) follow along on the public sidewalk, and as a non-participant, you aren't bound by any agreement so you can upload whatever you like. You might also be a non-participant follower in the street, which might not be allowed by the city, but that is between the police and you and not the organizer. Running down the middle of the street is not generally legal, but  the police might not care enough to ticket you.